# Selenium C# How to select following text input area:

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am unsure how I can select the input area coded below:

```
<input _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" placeholder="Name of the snapshot definition " type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
```

Furthermore, after the text value has been changed the above changes to the below:

```
 <input _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-control form-control-danger ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" placeholder="Name of the snapshot definition " type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
```

Same with below:

```
<input _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Description snapshot definition" type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
```

Changes to:

```
<input _ngcontent-c15="" class="form-control form-control-danger ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" placeholder="Description snapshot definition" type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
```

I have tried numerous combinations of the following:

```
element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched']");

element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[contains(@class,'form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched')]");

element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class,'form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched')]");

element = driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(@class,'form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched')]");

element = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("placeholder='Name of the snapshot definition '");
```

The full div for the area in question:

```
<div _ngcontent-c25="" class="form-group has-danger" ng-reflect-klass="form-group" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
<label _ngcontent-c25="">Name</label>
<input _ngcontent-c25="" class="form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" placeholder="Name of the snapshot definition " type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
<div _ngcontent-c25="" class="alert alert-danger">Required Field</div>
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
</div>
```

I do not need to extract any text. I need to enter it into the  area.

Comment: you want to select the text

Comment: Apologies, I want to select the area to send text to.

Comment: have you try with find by name

Comment: What name would be used? These text fields are dynamically added such that the _ngcontent-c15 is now _ngcontent-c19 after I have reloaded the page.

Comment: Name where it is??

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion and to help future visitors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
element = driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched']"));

string value = element.GetAttribute("placeholder");
```

and if you want to send text then

```
element.SendKeys("Text here");
```

and if you want to make some more specific to that field then use below xpath

```
 driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Name']/following-sibling::input")).SendKeys("username");
```

Comment: Hi! I had some success with the `driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Name']/following-sibling::input")).SendKeys("username");
` you posted however upon attempting to `.sendkeys()` the element is no longer found.

Comment: `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//label[text()='Name']/following-sibling::input")));
            element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Name']/following-sibling::input")); highlightElement(driver, element);` I have this code which runs fine however. It is only when I want to `SendKeys()` I now have the "not visible" issue.

Comment: Try this `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//lab‌​el[text()='Name']/fo‌​llowing-sibling::inp‌​ut"))); 
element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Name']/followin‌​g-sibling::input"));
element.SendKeys(text);
 highlightElement(driver, element);`

Comment: No. Despite the page looking as follows: https://i.gyazo.com/eb7998b5de66e856b4e0b690dc73ab7d.png Selenium will not find the element "visible" but can see it "exists".

Comment: can you share the site URL

Comment: I cannot unfortunately, it is an internal QA site for testing before product launch.

Comment: I managed to do it using JavaScript: `public void enterText(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, String Text)
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='" + Text + "'", element);
        }`   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Name of the snapshot definition']")).getAttribute("placeholder");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this returns "Cannot implicity convert type string to OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement" and removing the "GetAttribute" results in a timeout waiting for the element.

Comment: in which object are you trying to store data

Comment: The <input> :`<input _ngcontent-c25="" class="form-control form-control-danger ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" placeholder="Name of the snapshot definition " type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">`

Answer (score 0):

For send text you have to use `sendkeys` simply, this code in java please convert it into c sharp

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your values")).sendKeys("test");
```

For extracting text use `getAttribute` method

```
String Placehodlertxt= driver.findElement(By.xpath("your values")).getAttribute("placeholder"); 
System.out.println(Placehodlertxt);
```

Your xpaths are correct

Comment: XPath is not found. I just need to be able to access the <input> area such that I can first pass it to: `public void highlightElement(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
        }` and then send text to it.

Comment: yes you can use javascriptExecutpr, and in c sharp also IJavaScriptExecutor